# How can I solve Undefined class 'GoRouter'

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

I learning Flutter, and I suddenly happened in this situation.

I did

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade
restart IDE
clean project
rebuild project
sdk remove and reinstall
... etc
```

This is part of my code

```
// error : Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:go_router/go_router.dart'.
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:orury/presentation/routes/route_path.dart';

import '../pages/home/home_page.dart';
import '../pages/splash/splash_page.dart';

final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: RoutePath.splash,
      name: 'splash',
      builder: (context, state) => const SplashPage(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: RoutePath.home,
      name: 'home',
      builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
    ),
  ],
  initialLocation: '/splash',
);
```

It was going well, but suddenly it didn't work.
For your information, I gave dependencies such as Dartanalysis, dart_code_metrics, etc., but not after that. You can't eliminate dependency.

Is anyone can solve this problem? T_T

Comment: can you make sure you've `go_router` on `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: OMG It works! I really appreciate of you thanks :)